# Can I echo a request header value as the response body with vanilla Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to configure Nginx to return a response body created from a request header, or a request parameter? It looks like this can be done with the `echo` module, but if possible I would like to do it with a vanilla install of Nginx.

Basically I want to do the following, but obviously `return_body` doesn't exist, so what can I use instead?

```
location ~* ^/echo/(.+) {
  return_body $1;
}
```

or

```
location /echo_user_agent {
  return_body $http_user_agent;
}
```

If I install the `echo` module I could replace `return_body` with `echo`, but if at all possible it would be nice to be able to do this without having to install any extras, it seems to me like something simple like this should be possible to do without.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with [return](http://nginx.org/r/return) 200:

```
location = /echo_user_agent {
  return 200 $http_user_agent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngx_lua module`.

Like this:

```
body_filter_by_lua 'ngx.log(ngx.CRIT,ngx.arg[1])';
```

in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 add_header Path_Way1 ;
e.g.

```
add_header Path_Way1 $1;
```

where $1 is first path parameter